# Ownership, closures, FnOnce: much confusion

Tags: rust, closures, move, mutable, borrowing

I have the following snippet of code:

```
fn f<T: FnOnce() -> u32>(c: T) {
    println!("Hello {}", c());
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 32;
    let g  = move || {
        x = 33;
        x
    };

    g(); // Error: cannot borrow as mutable. Doubt 1
    f(g); // Instead, this would work. Doubt 2
    println!("{}", x); // 32
}
```

**Doubt 1**

I can not run my closure even once.

**Doubt 2**

... but I can invoke that closure as many times as I want, provided that I call it through `f`. Funnily, if I declare it `FnMut`, I get the same error as in doubt 1.

**Doubt 3**

What does `self` refer to in `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` traits definition? Is that the closure itself? Or the *environment*?
E.g. from the documentation:

```
pub trait FnMut<Args>: FnOnce<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Comment: did you read the compiler message ?

Comment: While the message says to make g mutable and that indeed allow the code to compile, why can an immutable g be used inside f but not outside?

Comment: because `FnOnce` have interior mutability.

Comment: All seems to be related to the `self` variable in the trait declaration (doubt 3): `FnOnce` has `self` but `FnMut` has `&mut self`.

Comment: @Stargateur please add more details on your answer

Comment: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html

Comment: @Stargateur "`FnOnce` has interior mutability" – no, that's not true. Calling an `FnOnce` _consumes_ the closure, but that has nothing to do with interior mutability.

Comment: @SvenMarnach that my way of seeing it.

Comment: @Stargateur "interior mutability" is jargon. It has a specific, defined meaning. Of course you are free to use the term to mean something else, but I don't consider this helpful for people learning Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some basics about the `Fn*` trait family is needed to understand how closures actually work. You have the following traits:

- [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), which, as the name implies, can only be run once. If we look at the docs page we'll see that the trait definition is almost the same as what you specified in your question. What is most important though, is the following: The "call" function takes `self`, meaning that it consumes the object which implements `FnOnce`, so like any trait function which takes a `self` as a parameter, it takes ownership of the object.
- [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), which allows for mutation of the captured variables, or in other words, it takes `&mut self`. What this means, is that when you make a `move || {}` closure, it will move any variables you reference which are outside the scope of the closure into the closure's object. The closure's object has a type which is unnameable, meaning that it is unique to each closure. This does force the user to take some kind of mutable version of the closure, so `&mut impl FnMut() -> ()` or `mut x: impl FnMut() -> ()`
- [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), which is generally considered the most flexible. This allows the user to take an immutable version of the object implementing the trait. The function signature for this trait's "call" function is the simplest to understand of the three, as it only takes a reference to the closure, meaning that you don't need to worry about ownership while passing it around or calling it.

To address your individual doubts:

- Doubt 1: As seen above, when you `move` something into a closure, the variable is now owned by the closure. Essentially, what the compiler generates is like the following pseudocode:

```
struct g_Impl {
    x: usize
}
impl FnOnce() -> usize for g_Impl {
    fn call_once(mut self) -> usize {

    }
}
impl FnMut() -> usize for g_Impl {
    fn call_mut(&mut self) -> usize {
        //Here starts your actual code:
        self.x = 33;
        self.x
    }
}
//No impl Fn() -> usize.
```

And by default it calls the `FnMut() -> usize` implementation.

- Doubt 2: What is happening here is that [closures are `Copy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44490) as long as each of their captured variables are `Copy`, meaning that the closure that is generated will be copied into `f`, so that `f` ends up taking a `Copy` of it. When you change the definition for `f` to take an `FnMut` instead, you get the error because you are facing a similar situation to doubt 1: You are trying to call a function which receives `&mut self` while you've declared the parameter to be `c: T` instead of either `mut c: T` or `c: &mut T`, either of which qualify for `&mut self` in the eyes of `FnMut`.
- Finally, doubt 3, the `self` parameter is the closure itself, which has captured or *moved* some variables into itself, so it now owns them.

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with two different kinds of closures here – `FnOnce` and `FnMut`. Both types of closures have different calling conventions.

If you define your closure as

```
let mut x = 32;
let g  = move || {
    x = 33;
    x
};
```

the compiler will infer the type of the closure as `FnMut`. While the closure returns the owned variable `x`, it can still be called multiple times, since `x` is `Copy`, so the compiler choses `FnMut` as the most general applicable type.

When calling an `FnMut` closure, the closure itself is passed by mutable reference. This explains your first question – calling `g` directly does not work unless you make it mutable, since otherwise you can't take a mutable reference to it. I also implicitly answered your third question here – `self` in the call methods of the `Fn` traits refers to the closure itself, which can be thought of as a struct containing all captured variables.

When calling `f(g)`, you pass the `FnMut` closure `g` as a `FnOnce` closure to `f()`. This is allowed since all `FnOnce` is a supertrait of `FnMut`, so every closure implementing `FnMut` also implements `FnOnce`. Now that the closure has been converted to `FnOnce`, it is also called according to the `FnOnce` calling convention:

```
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

The closure is passed in by *value* in this case, so the call *consumes* the closure. You can give away ownership of any value you own – it does not need to be mutable for this to work.

The reason why you can call `g` multiple times when calling it through `f()` is that `g` is `Copy`. It only captures a single integer, so it can be copied as many times as you want. Each call to `f()` creates a new copy of `g`, which is consumed when it is called inside of `f()`.